# Too many edges error on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, polygonize

I have this code that works perfectly for small rasters.

```
var image = ee.Image("users/parivash89/Cuneo_Reclassify")
  .toInt();

Map.addLayer(image);
Map.centerObject(image);

var classes = image.reduceToVectors({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});

var result = ee.FeatureCollection(classes);

Map.addLayer(result);

// Export the FeatureCollection to a SHP file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: result,
  folder: 'GEE_Polygonize',
  description:'Cuneo',
  fileFormat: 'SHP'
});
```

But gives me the following error while the raster input is large:

```
Layer 2: Tile error: Geometry has too many edges (3890235 > 2000000)
```

So I added this line :

```
// Simplify the feature
var featureSimple = ee.Feature(result).simplify({maxError: 10});
```

But it did not get simplified and I stil get the error. What should I change in my code? I need the resolution of 10m in my output so I cannot lower the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

By the time the simplify can happen, it's too late, you've already generated the giant polygon.  You will have to specify a larger scale to reduceToVectors.  Based on the error message, it looks like you'll need a scale of about 20.